# Ion-tabs dissapear only on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I have 2 ion-tabs on my homepage like this:

[image: ion-tabs]

After I click on New Game <- Pushes the page on top of the nav

This is what happens; as you can see, the android ion-tabs disappear & I have no way of returning back to the previous page

[image]

this is the "New Game" button code:

```
  goToNewGame() {
    this.nav.push(NewGamePage, {gamesPage: this});
  }
```